# ClassNotFoundException: PowerSaveModeBroadcastReciever

Tags: xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

My Xamarin app builds and runs fine for UWP, iOS and Android when I build from Visual Studio 15.9.15 or Visual Studio for Mac.

However, my main Windows 10 machine has Visual Studio 16.2.3. It consistently has a runtime problem with Android. On base.OnCreate(bundle) of MainActivity this happens:

`Java.Lang.ClassNotFoundException: 'Didn't find class "md51558244f76c53b6aeda52c8a337f2c37.PowerSaveModeBroadcastReceiver" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/MyApp.Droid-yK4jL0oczZScGLufK33mnA==/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/MyApp.Droid-yK4jL0oczZScGLufK33mnA==/lib/arm64, /data/app/MyApp.Droid-yK4jL0oczZScGLufK33mnA==/base.apk!/lib/arm64-v8a, /system/lib64, /system/vendor/lib64]]'`

When I build the Android from my MacBook, the app runs fine. I also have a different Windows 10 machine with Visual Studio 15.9.15 that builds and runs fine.

```
protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
{
        TabLayoutResource = Resource.Layout.Tabbar;
        ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback += (sender, cert, chain, sslPolicyErrors) => true;
        ToolbarResource = Resource.Layout.Toolbar;

        base.OnCreate(bundle); <-- ERROR HERE

        Xamarin.Essentials.Platform.Init(this, bundle);
        CrossCurrentActivity.Current.Init(this, bundle);

        global::Xamarin.Forms.Forms.Init(this, bundle);
        FFImageLoading.Forms.Platform.CachedImageRenderer.Init(enableFastRenderer: true);

        LoadApplication(new App());
}
```

The odd thing is that I can find the so-called missing file in the MyApp.Android\obj\debug\81\Android\bin\classes folder.

What's the deal with Visual Studio 2019?

Xamarin.Forms 3.6.0.344457

Comment: Can you try to update Visual studio and try again, or your can provide one demo that can reproduce this issue here, I can test it at my side.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Updating/Repairing Visual Studio did not solve the problem.

Luckily I was in a position where I could flatten my laptop and reinstall Windows 10 and Visual Studio 2019.

This allowed me to finally deploy to Android.